# Inventory Report - Item and Quantity

Tags: phrases

Greeting,

I work in Korean Company and having some trouble trying to make English translation of Inventory Status Report.

Suppose I have 5 different kind of items (=5 different item number), and each item has 2 quantity in stock, so I have total stock of 10 item quantities like the list below,

List of Item (each in stock quantity)
Item A(2), Item B(2), Item C(2), Item D(2), Item E(2)

Will it make sense to everyone if I make summary like this?

Inventory Summary:
Total Number of Item : 5
Total Stock Quantity : 10

Or could you suggest me better phrases to put in for 'Number of Item' and 'Stock Quantity' to make clear understanding?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

If you called the first line *Total Number of Items*, it would be understandable and correct English.

In your question, you mention *List of Item*, which if included in your report, would be better as *List of Items*.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the business of your company,  in general:

Classification of [inventory:](http://accountingtermsdictionary.com/accounting-terms-dictionary/atd-files/fm/inventory-classification-21.htm)

> Inventory items are classified based on
>   --> where they are in the production process
>
> 1. Merchandise
>      --> goods purchased from other entities
>      --> for the purpose of reselling to customers
> 2. Raw materials
>      --> materials and parts purchased from other entities
>      --> for the purpose of using them in the production process
> 3. Work in process
>      --> materials and parts currently in the production process
> 4. Finished goods
>      --> goods that completed the productions process
>      --> goods that are ready for sale to customers

Source: http://accountingtermsdictionary.com

Regarding example one for instance, you can refer to a quantity of 2 items for each type ( shoes, bags, gloves etc.) for a total of 10 items. 
In your inventory first you  make the list by type of item, then by total items.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct English to say *Total Number of Items* rather than *Total Number of Item*; but since "item" is ambiguous, I would use a different phrase: *Unique Item Numbers*.  While this might sound a bit less like what a businessperson would say and a bit more like what a mathematician would say, it has the advantage of being very difficult to misinterpret.